# Can not find the Wireless adaptor in ubuntu 16.04 with Lenovo ideapad 320

Tags: wireless

I can not find wireless adaptor in ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

[image]

```
rfkill list

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I don't know what is going wrong, I have wasted 2 days already. So please help

Thanks
Sanjay

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text. Rather post text as text and use the formatting tools provided here.

Comment: What happens if you `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-firmware` then reboot?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but after this again nothing is in wireless

Comment: See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and run the wireless script, then do `cat wireless-info.txt | nc termbin.com 9999` and post the URL

Comment: http://termbin.com/2vbo
this is the url

Comment: now it's 0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: http://termbin.com/j5wk  ??